# finding the a sub string at the end of a string in a sql query

Tags: mysql, regex

I am trying to search for domains ending in a keyword, e.g. 'travel', and would want to yield results like 'summertravel.com', 'besttravel.net'. However, if I search for the end of the domain

```
SELECT *  FROM `domains` WHERE `domain_name` LIKE '%com' ORDER BY domain_name ASC
```

then all its going to look for is the TLD, which will always be .com, .net, etc, not the actual domain name. I have limited knowledge when it comes to sql queries, however I think there may be some sort of regex, that can find the string up to the first '.', and search for the of that string.

Is that possible? Is there an easier way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this query:

```
SELECT * FROM DOMAINS WHERE DOMAIN_NAME LIKE '%travel.%'
```

Comment: simple and effective

Answer (score -1):

Use REGEXP like below:

```
SELECT *  FROM `domains` WHERE `domain_name` REGEXP 'travel' ORDER BY domain_name ASC
```

Query to find all the names, which contain 'travel'

I hope it will help

Comment: `REGEXP` is often slower than `LIKE`.

Comment: Then you have choice to use LIKE instead of using REGEXP